# send gif via mms

Tags: iphone, ios

```
NSString *gifPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"volleyball.gif"];
NSData *gifData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:gifPath];
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pasteboard setData:gifData forPasteboardType:@"com.compuserve.gif"];
[gifData release];
```

I use codes above to copy gif to clipboard and copy it to mms , then send it.
This do send the gif via mms but receiver can't recognize the data. Extension of attachment in the mms is null. But when I use System "copy" and do as before, receiver receives the mms and gif is recognized as gif.

So what should I do to make gif recognized?

Thanks. My English is poor ,hope you can understand.

Comment: I think when I copy the gif I should set something. But I don't know exactly what should set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work.  Try this.

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
if (bundle) 
{
   NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"volleyball" ofType:@"gif"];
    if (moviePath)
    {
        // copy to clipboard
        UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:moviePath];
        [pasteboard setData:data forPasteboardType:@"com.compuserve.gif"];            
    }
}
```